# Make a Flex div the same size as it's content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a Flexbox fit to exactly the size of it's content. In the below images it is indicated by the yellow border. In the styling when there is no wrapping, the yellow border fits the content exactly:

[image]

But when I add

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Then it starts adding padding/margins to the left and right sides (which I don't want)

[image: Actual div borders]

The style for the yellow div is:

```
.work-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 0px;

    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Minimum working example: https://pastebin.com/x37KgJiz

Comment: For that you either need media query's or a script, so which one do you prefer?

Comment: Media Queries if possible, unless JS is way easier

Comment: display:flex; is a container behaving at a block level , however , inline-flex will not totally wrap is content as you expect, either, if your children(img) have a known width, theb @mdia can help you to set breakpoints if the container area is about full screen width, if it is nested into column(s) less than window's widthh, then javascript will be the tool needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `work-container` doesn't know when the items wrap, hence will not adjust its own width automatically.

Since there is no property to be set, to make this work by itself, use either a script or media query to adjust the `work-container`'s width.

Stack snippet

```css
.work-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFF00;
}

.work-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}


@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .work-container {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .work-container {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .work-container {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" class="work-image" />
  </div>
</div>
```